# Generating 8 couples of integers

Tags: java, random, generator

I want to have 8 couples of integers such that they all have different coordinates and they are all within 5 units of each other (using the euclidean distance).

To clarify, I want to have

```
(x1, y1)

(x2, y2)

(x3, y3)

(x4, y4)

(x5, y5)

(x6, y6)

(x7, y7)

(x8, y8)
```

where the `xi`'s and `yi`'s are randomly generated integers (via `nextInt`) so that there are no indices `i`, `j` such that `xi = xj` and `yi = yj` and such that for all indices `i`, `j` `sqrt( (xi - xj)^2 + (yi - yj)^2 ) <= 5`.

What I did try is generating the first couple via nextInt and then using 7 intricated while loops to choose the 7 other couples but it takes way too long to compute:

```
    int r_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int r_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int p_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int p_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int b1_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int b1_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int b2_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int b2_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int g1_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int g1_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int g2_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int g2_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int m_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int m_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int w_x = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;
    int w_y = generateur.nextInt(2*n + 1) - n;

    Point2D pt_r = new Point2D(r_x, r_y);
    Point2D pt_p = new Point2D(p_x, p_y);
    Point2D pt_b1 = new Point2D(b1_x, b2_y);
    Point2D pt_b2 = new Point2D(b2_x, b2_y);
    Point2D pt_g1 = new Point2D(g1_x, g1_y);
    Point2D pt_g2 = new Point2D(g2_x, g2_y);
    Point2D pt_m = new Point2D(m_x, m_y);
    Point2D pt_w = new Point2D(w_x, w_y);



    boolean r_p = false;
    boolean r_p_b1 = false;
    boolean r_p_b1_b2 = false;
    boolean r_p_b1_b2_g1 = false;
    boolean r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2 = false;        
    boolean r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m = false;
    boolean r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m_w = false;

    while(!r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m_w){
        while(!r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m){
            while(!r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2){
                while(!r_p_b1_b2_g1){
                    while(!r_p_b1_b2){
                        while(!r_p_b1){
                            while(!r_p){

                                p_x = generateur.nextInt(n + 1) - n/2;
                                p_y = generateur.nextInt(n + 1) - n/2;

                                r_p = pt_r.test(p_x, p_y);


                            }

                            pt_p = new Point2D(p_x, p_y);
                            this.peon.setPos(pt_p);

                            b1_x = generateur.nextInt(n/2 + 1) - n/4;
                            b1_y = generateur.nextInt(n/2 + 1) - n/4;

                            r_p_b1 = (pt_r.test(b1_x, b1_y) && pt_p.test(b1_x, b1_y));

                        }

                        pt_b1 = new Point2D(b1_x, b1_y);
                        this.bugs1.setPos(pt_b1);

                        b2_x = generateur.nextInt(n/4 + 1) - n/8;
                        b2_y = generateur.nextInt(n/4 + 1) - n/8;

                        r_p_b1_b2 = (pt_r.test(b2_x, b2_y) && pt_p.test(b2_x, b2_y) && pt_b1.test(b2_x, b2_y));
                    }

                    pt_b2 = new Point2D(b2_x, b2_y);
                    this.bugs2.setPos(pt_b2);

                    g1_x = generateur.nextInt(n/8 + 1) - n/16;
                    g1_y = generateur.nextInt(n/8 + 1) - n/16;

                    r_p_b1_b2_g1 = (pt_r.test(g1_x, g1_y) && pt_p.test(g1_x, g1_y) && pt_b1.test(g1_x, g1_y) && pt_b2.test(g1_x, g1_y));
                }

                pt_g1 = new Point2D(g1_x, g1_y);
                this.guillaumeT.setPos(pt_g1);

                g2_x = generateur.nextInt(n/16 + 1) - n/32;
                g2_y = generateur.nextInt(n/16 + 1) - n/32;

                r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2 = (pt_r.test(g2_x, g2_y) && pt_p.test(g2_x, g2_y) && pt_b1.test(g2_x, g2_y) && pt_b2.test(g2_x, g2_y) && pt_g1.test(g2_x, g2_y));
            }

            pt_g2 = new Point2D(g2_x, g2_y);
            this.grosBill.setPos(pt_g2);

            m_x = generateur.nextInt(n/32 + 1) - n/64;
            m_y = generateur.nextInt(n/32 + 1) - n/64;

            r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m = (pt_r.test(m_x, m_y) && pt_p.test(m_x, m_y) && pt_b1.test(m_x, m_y) && pt_b2.test(m_x, m_y) && pt_g1.test(m_x, m_y)
                                 && pt_g2.test(m_x, m_y));
        }

        pt_m = new Point2D(m_x, m_y);
        this.merlin.setPos(pt_m);

        w_x = generateur.nextInt(n/64 + 1) - n/128;
        w_y = generateur.nextInt(n/64 + 1) - n/128;

        r_p_b1_b2_g1_g2_m_w = (pt_r.test(w_x, w_y) && pt_p.test(w_x, w_y) && pt_b1.test(w_x, w_y) && pt_b2.test(w_x, w_y) && pt_g1.test(w_x, w_y)
                                 && pt_g2.test(w_x, w_y) && pt_w.test(w_x, w_y));
    }

    pt_w = new Point2D(w_x, w_y);
    this.wolfie.setPos(pt_w);
```

where n is a power of 2

Comment: Great, you've clarified what you *want to have*... have you started any code to complete this? Please review [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then if possible [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52566574/edit) and update your question with code you have and specific questions about solving the problem.

Comment: There are 4 values in the range 0-3 inclusive, so there are 16 possible values with both x and y in the range 0-3. Pick any 8 of them; and the extreme points are only sqrt(18) apart, so they are all within 5 of each other.

Comment: I added the code I tried

Comment: "where n is a power of 2" but where is n in the description of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 25 coordinate pairs from (0, 0) to (4, 4).  You can immediately eliminate five of them: (0, 0), (1, 1) etc. with identical x and y values.  That leaves 20 possible values.  Of those 20, only two are more than 5 units apart: (0, 4) and (4, 0) which are sqrt(32) apart.  If you pick one of those two then you cannot pick the other.  Apart from that you can pick any in the given range.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach for a trial-and-error-algorithm is:

1. Randomly determine the first position vector.
2. Randomly determine the remaining seven position vectors in the neighborhood of the first position vector ±5 units in x and y direction.
3. After determination of a position vector and before the next position vector is determined, check if the position vector fullfills the conditions with regard to the already existing position vectors. If the conditions are not fulfilled discard the position vector and randomly determine a new one till all conditions are fullfilled.

The position vectors are determined in:

```
private void determinePositionVectors() {
    positionVector[0] = getFirstPositionVector();                       // 1.
    for (int i = 1; i < positionVector.length; i++) {
        if (positionVector[i] == null) {
            positionVector[i] = getRemainingPositionVectors();          // 2.
            while(!checkConditions(i)) {                                // 3.
                positionVector[i] = getRemainingPositionVectors();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
private Point2D getFirstPositionVector() {
    int n1 = random.nextInt(2 * MAXIMUM_POSITION_FIRST_POSITIONVECTOR + 1) - MAXIMUM_POSITION_FIRST_POSITIONVECTOR;
    int n2 = random.nextInt(2 * MAXIMUM_POSITION_FIRST_POSITIONVECTOR + 1) - MAXIMUM_POSITION_FIRST_POSITIONVECTOR;
    return new Point2D(n1, n2); 
}
private Point2D getRemainingPositionVectors() {
    int n1 = random.nextInt(2 * MAXIMUM_DISTANCE + 1) - MAXIMUM_DISTANCE;
    int n2 = random.nextInt(2 * MAXIMUM_DISTANCE + 1) - MAXIMUM_DISTANCE;
    Point2D p = positionVector[0].add(n1,n2);
    return p; 
}
private boolean checkConditions(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        double distance = positionVector[i].distance(positionVector[j]);
        boolean positionVectorsEquals = positionVector[j].equals(positionVector[i]);
        if (positionVectorsEquals || distance > MAXIMUM_DISTANCE) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The used constants and fields etc. are defined as:

```
package application;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

public class RandomVectors {

    private final static int NUMBER_OF_POSITIONVECTORS = 8;
    private final static int MAXIMUM_DISTANCE = 5;
    private final static int MAXIMUM_POSITION_FIRST_POSITIONVECTOR = 10;

    private static Random random = new Random();
    private Point2D[] positionVector = new Point2D[NUMBER_OF_POSITIONVECTORS];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomVectors randomVectors = new RandomVectors();
        randomVectors.determinePositionVectors();
        Arrays.stream(randomVectors.positionVector).forEach(p->System.out.print("(" + p.getX() + "," + p.getY() + ") "));
    }

    private void determinePositionVectors() {...} 
    private Point2D getFirstPositionVector() {...}
    private Point2D getRemainingPositionVectors() {...}
    private boolean checkConditions(int i) {...}
}
```

For some parameters (e.g. small values of MAXIMUM_DISTANCE and large values of NUMBER_OF_POSITIONVECTORS) the problem has no solution since there are too many position vectors on a too small space. This results in an endless while-loop in determinePositionsVectors. So far, no mechanism is integrated to prevent such an endless while-loop. A simple approach is to count the number of while-loops and stop the program when a threshold value is exceeded.